# Separating multiple inputs from a file into even or odd

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to take 200 randomizes numbers from a file, separate them into even and odd, and make them show up from lowest to highest in their even or odd parts.

I got the code for making it into even and odd from here but the original way had 10 instead of 200 and made the user input the numbers.

I reworked it into this but I get a repeat of the same number then an error that reads Exception thrown: write access violation with a mark near the odd[oddcnt++] = arr[i];

My code so far

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Random
{
private:
    int x, arr[200], even[200], odd[200], evncnt = 0, oddcnt = 0, i;
public:
    void readFile();
};
void Random::readFile()
{
    fstream File("Random.txt");
    if (File.is_open())
    {
        while(File >> x)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = x;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
                {
                    even[evncnt++] = arr[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    odd[oddcnt++] = arr[i];
                }
            }
            cout << "\n The even numbers are: ";
            for (i = 0; i < evncnt; i++)
            {
                cout << even[i] << "";
            }
            cout << "\n The odd numbers are: ";
            for (i = 0; i < oddcnt; i++)
            {
                cout << odd[i] << "";
            }
        }
        File.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Random file;
    file.readFile();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are combining way too much in `Random::readFile()`. It should simply read the values from the file into `arr[]` (or better into `std::vector<int> arr;`) and then call functions fill the even/odd arrays at the end. Your other member functions can then, e.g. `showeven()` and `showodd()` to display the wanted contents. Your output is the interface you show to the user. Your read and splitting is your implementation. Always keep your implementation and interface separate. (like chocolate and peanut-butter)

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are all wrong. This is how it should look

```
i = 0;
while (file >> x)
{
    arr[i] = x;
    i++;
}
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    if (arr[i]%2==0)
    ...
}
```

If you put one loop inside another (like you did) then the inner loop executes fully every time the outer loop executes once. That's not what you want (in this case).

Comment: upperr bound should be `i` instead of 200, so introduce another variable.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given already by John. So everything OK.

Additionally, I would like to show you the power of modern C++. Especially with using algorithms. You can write very elegant solutions.

Thers is no loop and only vey few variables.

You will of course not copy and paste it, because you will not understand it fully. But it should give you an **idea** how such a problem could be analysed, then designed, and then coded.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Random {
    std::vector<int> values{};
public:
    void readFile(const std::string& fileName);
    void printOdds();
    void printEvens();
};

void Random::readFile(const std::string& fileName) {

    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream inputFileStream(fileName); inputFileStream) {

        // Clear old content in our class
        values.clear();

        // Copy the contents from the vile into our vector
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(inputFileStream), {}, std::back_inserter(values));

        // sort the values
        std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());
    }
    else {  // File could not be opened
        std::cerr << "\n*** Error: File could not be opened: " << fileName << "\n\n";
    }
}
// Copy all odd values to std::cout
void Random::printOdds() {
    std::copy_if(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "), [](const int i) { return (i % 2) != 0; });
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

// Copy all even values to std::cout
void Random::printEvens() {
    std::copy_if(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "), [](const int i) { return (i % 2) == 0; });
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

// Driver code
int main() {

    Random r;
    r.readFile("r:\\random.txt");
    r.printEvens();
    r.printOdds();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With your example for the testing of the file it says that inputFileStream(filename) doesn’t work because a parenthesized initializer is not permitted

Comment: Hello. You need to complie with C++17 enabled. Then it will work.