# Ascending order of big group

Tags: c++

I have a file with around 200 numbers that need to be pun in ascending order then separated into even and odd, from an earlier question here I have fixed the even and odd code but I need to make it ascending order.

Comment: That's called *sorting* and if you have to implement the sorting yourself (rather than use `std::sort`) your text-books or class should have mentioned some ways.

Comment: I answered exactly this question already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300152/separating-multiple-inputs-from-a-file-into-even-or-odd/61302900#61302900 This is inlcuding sorting. See the lines ````// sort the values
        std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separating multiple inputs from a file into even or odd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300152/separating-multiple-inputs-from-a-file-into-even-or-odd)